# Connect void signal to void slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

For signal-slot connections, the signature of a signal is required to match the signature of the receiving slot. I wonder if it is legal to connect two void type signal and slot, like something as follows:

```
signals:
    void sendSignal(QVector<long int> mySignals);

private slots:
    void mySlot()

connect(this, SIGNAL(sendSignal(QVector<long int>)),
            this, SLOT(mySlot()),Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly legal, with the caveat that the slot will not receive the argument from the signal.

Comment: But the signal data are available within this class even if it differs from the one sending the signal, Is that right?

Comment: The argument from the signal is not available to this slot because the slot has a void parameter list.  If you wanted the QVector<long int> argument to be available to  the slot, you should change it to mySlot(QVector<long int>).  I am not addressing the cost of copying that entire list by not using a reference in this answer.